# Conditional formatting in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting

I'm trying to set up a formula in Google Sheets that applies to the whole sheet.  the formula would compare the dollar amount from column E to the dollar amount in column N. If it is equal I want to highlight the row. (column N is a formula that is the sum of several other columns)

I've tried several other formulas I've found online but none seem to be working.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a Custom Formula, to set up the comparison and lock it to those two columns.

- Select the whole sheet
- Choose "Conditional Formatting" from the "Tools" menu
- Choose your "Formatting style"
- Set the "Format cells if…" menu to "Custom formula is"
- Just below that, enter custom formula `=$E1=$N1`

[image: screenshot of demo Sheets state with some rows highlighted, and the Conditional Formatting sidebar open with the above steps taken.]

That custom formula will return `true` whenever E=N, and so apply the formatting to a given row. The dollar signs lock it so it only but always uses those columns. The 1 digits are not locked with dollar signs, so Sheets automatically changes it when checking each row for an E=N match.

Answer (score 0):

this is what you need:

```
=AND($E1=$N1, $E1<>"")
```

[image: 0]